# Why is my matplotlib not plotting?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tree

Here is my code:

```
from Trees import *
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import re
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

def read_file(file):
    words = []
    for line in wordFile:
        for word in line.split():
            words.append(re.sub("[^a-z]", "", word.lower()))

    return words

def pickle_object(object, fileName):
    with open(fileName, "wb") as output:
        pickle.dump(object, output, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

wordFile = open("texts/words1.txt", "r")
wordList = read_file(wordFile)

baseTrie = Trie()
trie2 = Trie()
bst = BinarySearchTree()
avl = AVLTree()

for item in wordList:
    baseTrie.add(item)

trieList = baseTrie.list("", [])

for word in trieList:
    bst.put(word, None)
    avl.put(word, None)
    trie2.add(word)

start = timer()
testTrieList = trie2.list("", [])
end = timer()
trieTime = end - start

start = timer()
bst.inorder()
end = timer()
bstTime = end - start

start = timer()
avl.inorder()
end = timer()
avlTime = end - start

#pickle_object(baseTrie, "Pickled Trees/trie.pkl")

print("Trie tree took %s seconds" % (trieTime))
print("Binary Search Tree took %s seconds" % (bstTime))
print("AVL tree took %s seconds" % (avlTime))

plt.plot(100, trieTime, label="Trie")
plt.plot(bstTime, label="BST")
plt.plot(avlTime, label="AVL")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to show the amount of time, in seconds, how long each of the time seconds took. However, whenever I try and run the file, it turns out like this:
[My plot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT1hj.png)

Why aren't the lines showing?

P.S. My output:

```
>>> Trie tree took 0.0350674204940301 seconds
>>> Binary Search Tree took 0.028901715849401904 seconds
>>> AVL tree took 0.030507586039193013 seconds
```

Comment: what's the output of your prints?

Answer (score 1):

I would go like this

```
abscissae = (10, 20, 30)
labels = ('Trie', 'BST', 'AVL')

plt.scatter(abscissae, (trieTime, bstTime, avlTime))
### E D I T — we want to compare the different timings, not the differences 
###           with respect to an arbitrary baseline!
plt.ylim(ymin=0)
plt.xticks(abscissae, labels)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

to obtain 
[image]